# Vertex algebras and factorization algebras

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, operads, vertex-algebras

It is often said that vertex algebras are a special case of factorization algebras. In particular, in their book "FAs in QFT" Costello/Gwilliam construct a functor from a certain class of 2d "holomorphic" factorization algebras to vertex algebras, by taking the cohomology. Does every vertex algebra arise in this way?

Comment: As far as I know only vertex algebras that are "universal envelopes" or related have been constructed this way. In particular there's no known construction of the irreducible affine Kac-Moody, rational W-algebras, chiral Hecke algebras, lattice vertex algebras, etc. in the Costello/Gwilliam framework. However, in answering to the title in the question, In Beilinson and Drinfeld there's an algebraic definition of factorization algebra.  When looking to translation equivariant FA (a la BD) on the line these are equivalent to Vertex algebras. There's no known construction BD <-> CG

Comment: It is not known whether W algebras arise this way. Also, I think you need a vertex _operator_ algebra structure to induce a BD chiral/factorisation algebra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, every $\mathbf{Z}$-graded vertex algebra arises from a factorization algebra on $\mathbf{C}$ with meromorphic operator product expansion.
See [Vertex Algebras and Costello-Gwilliam Factorization Algebras](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2012.12214.pdf).

This factorization algebra takes values in the symmetric monoidal category of *complete* bornological vector spaces.
I don't know if the underlying precosheaf of vector spaces satisfies codescent or homotopy codescent, but the precosheaf of complete bornological vector spaces does satisfy codescent.
The factorization algebra depends functorially on the $\mathbf{Z}$-graded vertex algebra, so there is a one-sided inverse to the functor from (certain) factorization algebras to $\mathbf{Z}$-graded vertex algebras.